# Is there any available DM script that can compare two images and know the difference

Tags: dm-script

Is there any available DM script that can compare two images and know the difference?

I mean the script can compare two or more images, and it can determine the similarity of two images, for example the 95% area of one image is same as another image, then the similarity of these two images is 95%.

The script can compare brightness and contrast distribution of images.

Thanks,

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I think your question got down-voted a bit (-not by me-), because it is not really a *coding* questions - i.e. a questions on how to program a specific thing - but rather a "does a solution for my problem exist?" type of question.

Answer (score 0):

This question is a bit ill-defined, as "similarity" between images depends a lot on what you want. 
If by "95% of the area is the same" you mean that 95% of the pixels are of identical value in images A & B, you can simply create a mask and `sum()` it to count the number of pixels, i.e.:
`sum( abs(A-B)==0 ? 1 : 0 )`

However, this will utterly fail if the images A & B are shifted with respect to each other even by a single pixel. It will also fail, if A & B are of same *contrast* but different absolute value.

Comment: One more question, if two images are different absolute value , we do normalize two images before subtraction,this method is ok or not

Comment: Depends on how you normalize and how exact your values are. Just think of it for a single pixel value. You may of course adjust the "masking condition", i.e. you can use `abs(A-B)<limit ? 1 : 0` or such. Also, you might be better of using the ration A/B rather than the difference as a condition, and so things like `abs(A/B-value)<limit ? 1 : 0`. The *critical* thing is the alignment of pixel values - if there is a shift (i.e. some drift between A & B) it does not work. What is your application?

Comment: BTW: best "check" you results by just displaying the mask image! i.e. just type `C = abs(A-B)?1:0` to create image C out of images A and B...

Answer (score 0):

I guess the intended question was to find similarity of two images in a fuzzy way. 
For these, one way is to do crosscorrelation. DM has this function. Like this,

```
image xcorr= CrossCorrelate(ref,img)
```

From xcorr, the peak position gives x- and y- shift between the two, the peak intensity gives "similarity" of the two. 
If you know there is no shift between the two, you can just do the sum and multiplication,

```
number similarity1=sum(img1*img2)
```

Another way to do similarity is calculate Euclidian distance of the two:

```
number similarity2=sqrt(sum((img1-img2)**2)).
```

"similarity2" calculates the "pure" similarity. "similarity1" is the pure similarity plus the mean intensity of img1 and img2. The difference is essentially this,

```
(a-b)**2=a**2+b**2-2*a*b.
```

The left term is "similarity2", the last term on the right is the "crosscorrelation" or "similarity1". 
I think "similarity1" is called cross-correlation, "similarity2" is called correlation coefficient. 
In example comparing two diffraction patterns, if you want to compute the degree of similarity, use "similarity2". If you want to compute the degree of similarity plus a certain character of the diffraction pattern, use "similarity1".